# Syntax to manually insert a UUID value in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, syntax, syntax-error, uuid

I have a table that was created as such:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DIM_Jour (
    jour_id uuid NOT NULL,
    AAAA int,
    MM int,
    JJ int,
    Jour_Semaine int,
    Num_Semaine int,

    PRIMARY KEY (jour_id)
);
```

I'm trying to manually insert some value for testing purposes. I know that eventually I would need to use a UUID generator.

```
INSERT INTO DIM_Jour (jour_id, AAAA, MM, JJ, Jour_Semaine, Num_Semaine) VALUES (
    292a485f-a56a-4938-8f1a-bbbbbbbbbbb1,
    2020,
    11,
    19,
    4,
    47
);
```

I get this error (or similar)

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "a485f"
 LINE 3:  292a485f-a56a-4938-8f1a-bbbbbbbbbbb1,
             ^
```

I've tried the different formats mentioned in the [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/curret/datatype-uuid.html), but it seems like it doesn't except any format. Is it a stupid syntax issue or am I missing something here? What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could pass it as a string literal and have the database implicitly convert it to a UUID:

```sql
INSERT INTO DIM_Jour (jour_id, AAAA, MM, JJ, Jour_Semaine, Num_Semaine) VALUES (
    '292a485f-a56a-4938-8f1a-bbbbbbbbbbb1',
    2020,
    11,
    19,
    4,
    47
);
```

But it's probably a good practice to be explicit about it and perform the cast yourself

```sql
INSERT INTO DIM_Jour (jour_id, AAAA, MM, JJ, Jour_Semaine, Num_Semaine) VALUES (
    '292a485f-a56a-4938-8f1a-bbbbbbbbbbb1'::UUID,
    2020,
    11,
    19,
    4,
    47
);
```

Comment: I thought I had tried with single quotes around it, but there must have been another error the time I imagine. Thanks for the confirmation. It works..

Answer (score 2):

You should use UUID generator and install [UUID extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html). PostgreSQL requires valid UUIDs conforming to [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122). Random strings are not valid UUIDs.

Also, as it is mentioned below, you should pass your UUIDs as quoted strings.

Comment: Note that starting with Postgres 13, the extension is no longer needed to generate UUID. Postgres how has `gen_random_uuid()` built-in

Comment: True. It's one of the options.